# Using Bind's Include attribute with HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've an action that accepts an HttpPostedFileBase, but the form that posted this file might name the input "File" or "FileToUpload".  Since I can't change the posting form's file input name, I set the Bind attribute's Include property to the list of names I'll accept.

However, when the form with the file input named "File" posts to this action, then the FileToUpload parameter is null.  See below.

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult UploadFile([Bind(Include = "File,FileToUpload")] 
        HttpPostedFileBase FileToUpload)
    {
        // If the file was posted with the name "File", then FileToUpload is null
        return View();
    }
```

Can anyone explain why this is behaving this way?  Is there something I'm misunderstanding about the Bind attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind include simply says if it finds the name of that attribute - then bind it, otherwise exclude it. Since its missing in your case, it would be expected to be null. Think of a scenario where my model is "Customer" and I only want the ModelBinder to bind to CustomerId and EmailAddress, and exclude any other property. In that case I would specify Bind[Include="CustomerId, EmailAddress"]
However - if EmailAddress is missing, then it would still be null